# Empty kernel processes on CentOS vps : 2 different servers

Tags: centos, process, virtualization

I'm not sure I'm asking correctly, or perhaps I'm just looking at the wrong things. I'm migrating from one CentOS Vps (on an OpenVZ box) to another CentOS VPS (on a VMWare box).

- VPS #1 = CentOS release 6.5 (Final) - Linux version 2.6.32-042stab061.2 (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
- VPS #2 = CentOS release 6.5 (Final) Linux version 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)

Essentially identical setup, i.e., LAMP, updated to latest via YUM. However, on VPS #1, there aren't that many processes, just your standard as expected from the setup.

On VPS #2, there are many more processes, and I don't really understand why. Granted they seem to be "empty" processes (0% CPU, 0% Memory), but why are they there?

I don't think it would be because one VPS is on OpenVZ and the other on VMWare, or is it?

#### VPS #1

[image: VPS 1]

#### VPS #2

[image: VPS 2A]
[image: VPS 2B]

#### Questions

- Can someone please explain to me why there are these differences between these 2 systems?
- Why are their more processes on one system vs. the other?

Comment: Welcome to *nix.SE! Please note that, in the future, you should avoid posting images of terminal output. This site has inline code blocks that allow for their formatting (and scrolling if long enough) beautifully. If, however, you feel that there is just _too_ much output for inline paste, there are plenty of good text paste clients (like [ix](http://ix.io) and [sprunge](http://sprunge.us)) which you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of processes in OpenVZ is normal. OpenVZ is a container technology not really a virtualization technology like VMWare or VirtualBox. In VMWare there is a technology called the hypervisor which is integrated into the host system's kernel.

On a OpenVZ system the guest systems share the same Linux Kernel. There fore there is in fact only 1 Linux kernel running, not one for every single guest.

Here's output from one of my OpenVZ guests:

```
$ ps -eaf
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:18 init [3]      
root      7699 22497  1 14:05 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/0 
root      7769  7699  2 14:05 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root      7794  7769  0 14:05 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -eaf
apache   12221 25901  1 10:41 ?        00:02:33 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13386 25901  1 Sep17 ?        00:14:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14030 25901  1 07:22 ?        00:05:37 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14038 25901  1 07:22 ?        00:05:36 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     21967     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
rpc      22317     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:22 portmap
rpcuser  22349     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd
root     22419     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/rsyslogd.pid -m 0
root     22435     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:49 ypbind
root     22457     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:15:42 automount
root     22485     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:13:33 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a
root     22497     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root     22508     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid
root     22526     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:23 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp    23558     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
root     23577     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:03 crond
root     23585     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam -n 2
root     23586 23585  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam -n 2
root     23594     1  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:07 /usr/sbin/uptimed
apache   24238 25901  1 04:34 ?        00:07:22 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     25901     1  0 Sep16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

The OpenVZ project's website has a fairly good overview of the differences in container virtualization technologies vs. virtual machine technologies.

- https://wiki.openvz.org/WP/Containers_vs_VMs

#### Getting rid of the "empty" processes

These are not empty processes. In a VM environment your virtualizing at the hardware layer, so the guest OSes have to provide more of the core processes that they'd be obligated to have if they were running on bare metal.

With container technologies such as OpenVZ/Docker/LXC, you're virtualizing at the process level, and so you're under a different set of obligations. All your containers can benefit by sharing a single Linux kernel instead.

Comment: Ok, Thanks SLM! I had no idea. I will get used to it!